# Java argument with different static and dynamic types?

Tags: java, polymorphism, dynamictype

I'm learning cs61b Berkeley open course, and was puzzled with this question(question 1, line 7):
https://sp18.datastructur.es/materials/discussion/examprep04sol.pdf

```
c.play(d);    // Method D is called
```

so in this case `d` has static type of `Dog` and dynamic type of `Corgi`, in compile-time `Method D` is recorded, then why in run-time it still calls `Method D` rather than `Method E` based on its dynamic type?

Comment: "Linking" in Java is done at compile time based on the declared (static) type.

Comment: virtual method calls only applies to the left operand as the signature of the method is determined at compile time and doesn't change at runtime. This is to simplify method lookup esp i.e. you could have any number of combinations which could match other wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the exercise was to test your understanding of using static and dynamic types for method dispatch.

In your situation, Java compiler must make two decisions:

- Whose method, `Dog`'s or `Corgi`'s, needs to be called, and
- In case of `Corgi`'s methods, which overload needs to be called.

The first decision is made based on the left side of the call expression `c.play(d)`, i.e. `c`, which is `Corgi`. If `Corgi` is further subclassed into, say, `Cardigan` and `Pembroke`, the methods of the corresponding subclass would be called at runtime based on the dynamic type.

The compiler is concerned only with the static type of `c`: it needs to make sure that `play` method taking `Dog` would be available at runtime. The virtual call itself is performed by JVM based on the dynamic type of the `c` object.

The second decision, on which overload needs to be called, is also done at compile time. This is important, because it "locks in" the decision at compile time. That is why the right answer is `"D"`, even though the object `d` has the dynamic type of `Corgi`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Yes I totally understand the first decision part, for second decision I don't quite get what ''lock in at compile time'' means, do you mean in overloaded method selection process only static type of argument matters? (in contrast with in overridden method selection process dynamic type makes the final decision)

Comment: @SouthParker That’s right, the decision on the overload is based only on static types of method arguments.

Comment: Cheers I also found the same answer in duplicate question.